# Java Send outlook meeting request ical4j

Tags: java, outlook, calendar, invite, ical4j

I am trying to send Outlook meeting request with Java. When I send in UTC, Outlook adjusts the timezone to client's calendar and shows. What should I do to make the client not to adjust automatically to client's timezone?
Ex.: If I send a meeting for 5PM Pacific to a client who is in Eastern, it should still appear as 5PM in client's calendar.
My request has:

```
DTSTART:20181029T070000Z
DTEND:20181030T070000Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an event to appear at the same time of the day, regardless of the timezone of the attendee, you want to use floating time. It is essentially the same syntax, without the final Z. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 , e.g.

```
DTSTART:20181029T170000
```

for an event that shall start at 5PM wherever the location of the recipient.

Beware though that this is a really strange thing to do for meetings. If you have an organiser in one time zone and attendees in other timezones on a conference call, they will end up dialing in at different times. Is this really what you want ?

Comment: Hi Arnaud Quillaud, Thanks for your reply. Its really worked in Outlook 365 and 2016. But its not working in outlook 2013. In outllok 2013, it shifts based on the client's calendar settings. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.